# c# sqlconnection

Tags: c#, sql

I've made a class so I can connect fast and easy to my database. 
Unfortunately it isn't working:(

so this is my main :

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection Connect = sqlConn.openSqlConnection();
            Connect.Open();
            string querytest = "select * from lars.Kmstand";
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(querytest, Connect);
            SqlDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                test.Add(rdr.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

And this is the class of course I've changed the connection string a bit :)

```
class sqlConn
{
    public static SqlConnection openSqlConnection()
    {
        string Password = "Data Source=mssql.--.net;User ID=lars;Password=***********";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Password)) 
        {
            return conn;
        }
    }
    public static void closesqlConn(SqlConnection conn)
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Why doesn't this work?

And does somebody know perhaps a better way>?

Thankss!

Comment: **what** does not work?

Comment: also the format of your connection string is incorrect, just search and try there are many questions asked on it in SO

Comment: Also, rdr.ToString() returns the class name of the SqlDataReader not the content of any field.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the connection wrapped in a using statement...

When the calling code gets the connection, it will already be disposed.

No need for a wrapper in my opinion, just create the SqlConnection object directly.